# re-direct output message from java console to jTextArea or jLabel

Tags: java, swing, perl

I want to visualize my message from java console to jpanel or jTextArea , I've created 2 classes : the first that contains my output message from perl script "hello world !" and i want to see this message in my jtextarea from the other class when i click a jButton from the second class --> this is my first class of my script

```
package escudo;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
public class MediocreExecJavac { 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
           // Run the process
           Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl script\\hello.pl");
           // Get the input stream
           InputStream is = p.getInputStream(); 
           // Read script execution results
           int i = 0;
           StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
           while ( (i = is.read()) != -1)
               sb.append((char)i); 
           System.out.println(sb.toString()); 
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
   } 
}
```

and this where i want to visualize the hello world message in this Jtextarea when i click the GO Jbutton

```
package escudo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class test extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    test frame = new test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(48, 71, 324, 180);
        contentPane.add(textArea);

        JButton btnGo = new JButton("go");
        btnGo.setBounds(159, 23, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnGo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

> when i click the GO Jbutton

First you need to add an ActionListener to the button. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write an ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). The code in the ActionListener should invoke a method in your class, not a separate class.

> the first that contains my output message from perl script "hello world !" and i want to see this message in my jtextarea

Then you need to redirect the System.out.println(..) statements to the text area. Check out [Message Console](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) for one way to do this.